# Custom validation using IF() and Len()

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I made a custom phone format ###-###-#### so that a phone # can be entered only as 5555555555 => 555-555-5555 or as 555-555-55555.

I need a non-vba solution i.e one I can enter in the Data Validation window that checks the cell length and validates it if the length is 10 OR 12.

I have been trying for a long time but can not get it by trial and error or googling.

My best guess is (which does not work)

```
=IF((LEN(E2:E32)=12,0),( LEN(E2:E32)=10,0))
```

Thanks

Comment: Select Range E2:32 > Click on Data Validation > In settings Tab > Select Allow as Custom > Formula `=(OR(LEN(E2)=12,(LEN(E2)=10)))` . I hope that shud work.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this! Can anyone revert that or, if you edit the question, I can clear it.

Comment: Thanks Santosh, but it did not work, I will give Bathsheba's answer a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy since Excel does not have a built in pattern matching function - you can only use built in functions in validation checks.

There is a solution though!

Fortunately you can check validation based on the state of a dependent cell. That's the approach we'll take here.

1) Your first job is to *format the telephone number as text* (my functions assume you've done this) so Excel doesn't trim leading zeros. In practice you'd format the whole column that way. Let's assume cell A1 will contain the phone number.

2) The validation formula will be ridiculously large if you attempt to put it in one cell and will be difficult to maintain. What we will do is put the validation stuff "off-spreadsheet"; i.e. in a column that's normally not visible to the user. That said, we'll use columns B,C and D for clarity. (Just cut and paste these elsewhere once you're done).

3) In B1 put `=OR(C1,D1)`

4) In C1 put `=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A1)=10,VALUE(A1)*0 + 1,FALSE),FALSE)`. This validates the format with no dashes.

5) In D1 put `=IFERROR(IF(OR(LEN(A1)=12,LEN(A1)=13),IF(AND(MID(A1,4,1)="-",MID(A1,8,1)="-"),VALUE(LEFT(A1,3) & MID(A1,5,3) & MID(A1,9,32767)) * 0 + 1,FALSE),FALSE),FALSE)`. This validates the format with the dashes.

Three tricks I'm using are (i) IFERROR is used to write False if the result would otherwise be #VALUE. This allows me to be more woolly in the programming, and (ii) the VALUE(n) * 0 + 1 pattern returns 1 if n is a number and, conveniently will compute #VALUE and delegate this to the surrounding function if n is not a number. Finally (iii) the 32767 in the MID function allows us to compare the remaining characters in a string without having to use a more clumsy RIGHT expression. 32767 is the limit on the number of characters in a cell. Perhaps I'm out by 1 here; no downvotes due to that please ;-)

6) Lastly, for cell A1, choose custom validation and set =B1 as the validation formula.

This does it! It will pass all your three formats:

5555555555, 555-555-5555 or 555-555-55555 where you've used 5 as a wildcard digit.

Comment: Hello Bathsheba this works perfectly! Thank you, also thanks for the explanation that was equally helpful.